# A reliable aluminium battery that charges in a minute. What's the catch?

Tags: material-science, batteries

This article

> [Ultra-fast charging aluminum battery offers safe alternative to conventional batteries](http://phys.org/news/2015-04-ultra-fast-aluminum-battery-safe-alternative.html), phys.org.

reports on the finding by a Stanford group of an aluminium-ion battery that can apparently compete in most respects with lithium-ion ones, lasts for thousands of cycles, and can be recharged in about one minute.

> An ultrafast rechargeable aluminium-ion battery. M.-C. Lin et al. [*Nature* (2015)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1038/nature14340) (epub ahead of print).

To read both the paper and the phys.org report, everything is fantastic and this is the solution to all world problems, which makes me a bit suspicious. What's the catch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They write that capacity is still half of that of lithium ion batteries, although this can probably be improved. However, this does look like a real breakthrough.